# Google Colab: Is there are way to set Tensorflow 2 as default?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab. My code needs Tensorflow 2 to run, but everytime I connect to a new session I have to ungrade to Tensorflow 2, since GC's default is 1.15.0
Is there a way to set TF 2 as default, that I don't have to upgrade it everytime I use? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try running `%tensorflow_version 2.x` in the first cell? Or running this command is the issue you want to resolve?

Comment: it will become default soon, as per warning in Colab. until then use the easy recipe from @sebastian-sz.

Comment: @sebastian-sz yeah I want to solve that issue. Running it takes (little, but still) time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `%tensorflow_version 2.x` in the first cell should solve this.